# Taking max number from one dataframe based on there 'timestamp' and 'id' of another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to see what is the last amount is given by customer. and the last time of per customer sale.

I have two dataframes: 
DF1:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|    ref_ID|     Amount|  Sale time|
|  11111111|        100| 2014-04-21|
|  22222222|         60| 2013-07-04|
|  33333333|         12| 2017-08-02|
|  22222222|         90| 2014-05-02|
|  22222222|         80| 2017-08-02|
|  11111111|         30| 2014-05-02|
+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

DF2:

```
+----------+----------+
|        ID|  num_sale|
|  11111111|         2|
|  33333333|         1|
|  22222222|         3|
+----------+----------+
```

I Need this output:

```
+----------+-----------+---------------+----------------+
|        ID|   num_sale| last_sale_time|last_sale_amount|
|  11111111|          2|     2014-05-02|              30|
|  33333333|          1|     2017-08-02|              12|
|  22222222|          3|     2017-08-02|              80|
+----------+-----------+---------------+----------------+
```

I am trying to do is:

```
last_sale_amount= []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    try:
        last_sale_amount= max(df2.loc[df['id'] == row['f_id'], 'last_sale_time'])
        print(str(last_sale_amount))
        num_attempt.append(last_sale_amount)
    except KeyError:
        last_sale_amount.append(0)

ad['last_sale_amount'] = last_sale_amount
```

Comment: Are you sure your desired output is reflecting the correct output? Shouldn't `last_sale_time` for `11111111` be `2014-05-02` and `22222222` be `2017-08-02` based on `DF1`?

Comment: sorry there was a mistake in post. now i update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use group by with sorted sales time and take there last row.

```
df1 = df1 .sort_values('Sale time').groupby('ref_ID').last().reset_index()
```

And Then merge it with dataframe 2 (df2).

```
df2= df2.merge( df1, left_on = "ID", right_on = "ref_ID", how="left" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupby to get the maximum sale time from each column then merge back the info from df1 and df2

```py
df_maxsale = df1.groupby('ref_ID')['Sale time'].max().to_frame().reset_index() \
                .merge(df1, how='left', on=['ref_ID', 'Sale time']) \
                .merge(df2, how='left', left_on='ref_ID', right_on='ID')
```

note: `.max()` returns a series with `ref_ID` as the index, so you need to call `to_frame().reset_index()` so that `ref_ID` is a column and you can merge on it and `Sale time`